# Do I have to run emulator or the editor is enough

Tags: android

I would like to test my android on difference screen sizes. I use eclipse, Should I run it on the emulator (AVD) with different screens/densities? Or would I be ok just using the editor and changing the skin to match what I want? I just want to see how my buttons/images look like.

Thank you

Comment: Different devices have difference screen densities. You have to match them if you want to test them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making an app for tablet and phone then you really should consider running it at least on an emulator. I personally prefer using actual devices. Tablets, phones, etc. If that's not an option then yea, I'd make a couple `AVDs` and test it out. It's better safe than sorry. You can go into Window --> Android Virtual Device Manager ---> Device Definitions and there is a bunch of pre-made `AVDs` for actual devices. Just click the clone button and then set them up. Easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Just changing the screen sizes in the editor should be enough for getting a sense of where things are. Remember to always test your application periodically on the emulator and (preferably) on actual devices after the introduction of every new feature.